# Echo wont show if the condition is true or false

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I want to do is  do nothing if the email is empty, echo 1 if the condition is true and echo 0 if the condition is false.

My problem is even if the condition is true echo wont show up and if false still the echo wont show.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "test";

$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(!empty(@$_POST['email'])) {

        $name = @$_POST['name'];
        $age = @$_POST['age'];
        $address = @$_POST['address'];
        $gender = @$_POST['gender'];
        $email = @$_POST['email'];

        $dupesql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE email = :email ";

        $dupesql = $dbc->prepare($dupesql);
        $dupesql->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $dupesql->execute();
        $num_rows = $dupesql->rowCount(); 

        if($num_rows === 0) 
        {

        echo "1";
        $q = "INSERT INTO students(name, age, address, gender, email ) VALUES(:name, :age, :address, :gender, :email)";

        $query = $dbc->prepare($q);
        $query->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $query->bindParam(':age', $age);
        $query->bindParam(':address', $address);
        $query->bindParam(':gender', $gender);
        $query->bindParam(':email', $email);

        $results = $query->execute();

        }else{
        echo "0";
        exit;
        }   
}       

?>
```

Comment: put a die after each echo statement and see if it is displaying

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is not checking wether the email is empty. It is checking wether any rows were returned. You need to relocate the else section of your if statement as below.

```
if(!empty(@$_POST['email'])) {
  // code here
  echo "1";
  // code here
}else{
  echo "0";
  exit;
}
```

Comment: there is a if statement inside empty condition if email is available or not.

Comment: if available echo 1 if not echo 0

Comment: try to use `if(isset(@$_POST['email']))` instead of `if(!empty(@$_POST['email']))`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you return wrong data type from `$dupesql->rowCount();`. Try to write variable through `var_dump();` or use `==` insted of `===`. Or you also can have empty `$_POST['email']` variable

Comment: my code was working before i put the if!empty statement in my code